# The unit circle is not compact under the Euclidean metric?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Consider the unit circle and the usual Euclidean metric $d$ on it.  The every pair of points on this circle are less than or equal to 2 units from each other.

I think that the unit circle would be compact with respect to the metric topology if I can show that every sequence of points on the circle has a convergent subsequence.

But consider the sequence ${a_n}$ where $a_n = (0,1)$ if $n$ is odd and $a_n = (1,0)$ if $n$ is even.  This sequence does not converge.  Hence the unit circle is not compact?  What m I missing?  I am conflicted by the fact that closed and bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such as the unit circle are compact.

Note that I am thinking about this while studying topology, not analysis.

Comment: This sequence does not covnerge, but it has convergent subsequence, for instance $(a_{2n})_{n\in \mathbf N}$.

Comment: @tomasz Every sequence on the unit circle has a convergent subsequence?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Do you belive $[-1,1]$ is not compact just because $\left(\sin(n)\right)_{n=1}^\infty$ does not converge?  Perhaps you don't have the definition of [sequentialy compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequentially_compact_space) quite right.

Answer (score 4):

The sequence
$$
(0,1), \quad(1,0), \quad(0,1),\quad(1,0),\quad (0,1), \quad(1,0),\quad \ldots
$$
does not converge, but it has a convergent subsequence:
$$
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
(0,1), & (1,0), & (0,1), & (1,0), & (0,1), & (1,0), &  \ldots \\
\uparrow & & \uparrow & & \uparrow
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Oh yes it is.  (As you noted) $S^1$ is a closed an bounded subset of  $\mathbb R^2$, hence compact by Heine-Borel.

Not every sequence necessarily converges in a compact space.   We are only guaranteed a convergent *subsequence*.